# Putting a key from a array list onto a jbutton? Also how to implement an KeyListener

Tags: java

I need to make the JButton show a random key from the alphabet.  Here is my code so far :

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
    Random r = new Random();
    char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    JButton b = new JButton(myStringArray[c]);
    JButton b2 = new JButton(myStringArray[c]);
    JButton b3 = new JButton(myStringArray[c]);
    JButton b4 = new JButton("");
}
```

But I am receiving errors.  What am I doing wrong?  Also I want to implement an KeyListener so that when the random key that is shown on the JButton, when pressed it will make that jbutton go away and make a new one pop up on top.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `I want to implement an KeyListener so that when the random key that is shown on the JButton, when pressed it will make that jbutton go away and make a new one pop up on top.` - Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817283/how-to-make-one-actionperfomed-on-a-jbuttin-matrix-java/33817303#33817303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think you shouldn't create `Random` object for each time of this call.
- `c` is used as an array index, so it should be an `int`, not `char`. Also, do not add `'a'` to `c` because it just leads to out-of-range exception.

Try this (not tested):

```
private Random r = new Random(); // a field of this class

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    int c = r.nextInt(26);
    String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    JButton b = new JButton(myStringArray[c]);
    JButton b2 = new JButton(myStringArray[c]);
    JButton b3 = new JButton(myStringArray[c]);
    JButton b4 = new JButton("");
}
```

Comment: Had to make different variable of c for it work properly but it worked!.  Now how do implement it so it removes the button and create a new one with a different assigned key